# "Validation Rule" in MS Access for a string column for having only numeric digits

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Is it possible to have a "Validation Rule" in MS Access for a column of text/string data type that allows only numeric digits? And a "Validation Rule" that allows only alphabets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a rule that will only allow numeric digits you can use. `Is Null OR Not Like "*[!0-9]*"` This will reject anything that is not a number.  You can do the same thing with alpha characters with `Is Null OR Not Like "*[!a-z]*"`

Have a look at [this link](http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html) for more examples of what you can do with validation rules. If you are restricting a field to only allows numeric digits why not make the field numeric?

Comment: RE: "why not make the field numeric?" - That can get awkward if the field really *is* a text field that can contain only digits, especially when leading zeros might be involved.